# How to normalize coordinates inputs for neural networks

Tags: input, neural-network, normalization

I am doing project regrading signature recognition using Neural Networks.So in there I did all feature extraction activities.In result of feature extraction,there are some features which are as set of coordinates(x and y).So I know before put those as neural network input it should be normalize.So I don't know the exact way to normalize coordinates before it give as NN input.Is there are any method to approach that problem?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Serialize 'em!

#### Given that your cluster algorithm returns data in this manner (or something similar)

```
# output from        |output coordinates
# cluster algorithm  |
[_ X X _ _]           (0,0) (0,1) (0,2) (0,3) (0,4)
[_ X _ X _]           (1,0) (1,1) (1,2) (1,3) (1,4)
[_ X X _ _]           (2,0) (2,1) (2,2) (2,3) (2,4)
[_ X _ _ _]           (3,0) (3,1) (3,2) (3,3) (3,4)
[_ X _ _ _]           (4,0) (4,1) (4,2) (4,3) (4,4)
```

#### Then we serialize it (that is: just concatinate the lines)

```
# output from cluster algorithm, serialized:
[_ X X _ _ _ X _ X _ _ X X _ _ _ X _ _ _ _ X _ _ _ ]

# the corresponding coordinates for instructional purposes:
[(0,0) (0,1) (0,2) (0,3) (0,4) (1,0) (1,1) (1,2) (1,3) (1,4) (2,0) (2,1) (2,2) (2,3) (2,4) (3,0) (3,1) (3,2) (3,3) (3,4) (4,0) (4,1) (4,2) (4,3) (4,4)]
```

And feed this into your network!

---

#### When it comes to normalization

Your clustering algorithm should "cluster your input images enough", so that the number of inputs is acceptable.

Comment: Then whats happen when coordinates are greater than 1(x or y value > 1)? Because I'm using MLP with Back propagation learning algorithm.So it accepts input  value between 0,1 [0,1].so how to overcome this?  Thank you very much  for your valuable consideration regarding this matter.

Comment: _I appended some information to my answer._ As you can see, we ignore the coordinates. The network will recieve an `1` as input, if the cluster algorithm returned an `X` for the corresponding input signal. The coordinate-oriented data is turned into an input **vector**.