# Coordinate normalization for NN input in matlab

Tags: matlab, input, coordinates, neural-network, classification

I am trying to implement a classification NN in Matlab.
My inputs are clusters of coordinates from an image. (Corresponding to delaunay triangulation vertexes)
There are 3 clusters (results of the optics algorithm) in this format:
[image]

( Not all clusters are of the same size.). Elements represent coordinates in euclidean 2d space . So (110,12) is a point in my image and the matrix depicted represents one cluster of points.
Clustering was done on image edges. So coordinates refer to logical values (always 1s in this case) on the image matrix.(After edge detection there are 3 "dense" areas in an image, and these collections of pixels are used for classification). There are 6 target classes.

So, my question is how can I format them into single column vector inputs to use in a neural network?
(There is a relevant answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18099345/how-to-normalize-coordinates-inputs-for-neural-networks) but I would like some elaboration if possible. ( I am probably too tired right now from 12 hours of trying stuff and dont get it 100% :D :( )
Remember, there are 3 different coordinate matrices for each picture, so my initial thought was, create an nn with 3 inputs (of different length). But how to serialize this?

Here's a cluster with its tags on in case it helps:
[image]

Comment: Are the clusters the input, or the points? If clusters, then you should input whatever describes the cluster (mean+variance for example). If points, you should input the assignments like done in the question you linked. In the first case you need a constant number of clusters, in the second you need a constant number of points.

Comment: I don't know if I understood your problem; do you want to train a nnet to classify single coordinates as belonging to one of the clusters 1, 2, 3?

Comment: The points are the inputs but they are organized in 3 clusters. I have a constant number of clusters. The clustering is done in order to extract specific regions of interest in my image. There are 3 clusters of points each time.The points are separated in clusters because segmentation is a factor. So the goal is that each time, the classification works like for example "cluster 1 is a circle, cluster 2 is a line, cluster 3 is a circle, so the image is classified in category #1". The number of points in each cluster is variable, but I always have 3 clusters.

Comment: @LordHenryWotton sorry, perhaps I was not clear. I dont want to classify the coordinates that belong to clusters. That I already have. I want to classify an image that can belong to six different classes. These 3 clusters, have variations in shape that define the image alltogether. In short, it is  classification based on the shapes of the clusters.

Comment: Okay, so clusters are features of an image. For each image, you could then create (1) a matrix X with each row being the fraction of points belonging to each cluster, that is, x_i=[cluster_1/N, cluster_2/N, cluster_3/N] where N=number of points of the image, and (2) y = one of the categories (1 ... 6). You should be able to train a nnet in Matlab with X and y.

Comment: My understanding of the answer in the other question is that for my case (in the image provided) my input should be something like [(110,12),(109,13)...] etc?? that doesnt sound correct.. :S (wrote that at the same time with your second answer.. now reading it..)

Comment: Say you have 4 images 100 points each. Say this is the distribution of points per cluster: p1=[30 30 40], p2=[100 0 0], p3=[10 90 0], p4=[0,0,100]. Clusters 1, 2 and 3 correspond to the columns of p_i. Suppose you have the following labels for these images, y=[1,2,1,3]. My view is that you should create a matrix of predictors like X=[p1;p2;p3;p4]/100 and use a class vector y to learn a classifier using something like svmtrain or other method. You could use other predictors based on the cluster information, the fractions are just one idea.

Comment: OK that's very helpful. Hadn't thought about it. One last thing: OK i create the Pi matrix for each image. Clear enough. And each element in Pi columns represents coordinates of a point in the cluster. Can they be in coordinate *form* to be input in an nn? I mean can the column in P1 be [(110,12),(109,13)...] or do I have to do something else? (for example change it to correspond to enumeration? ie point (110,12) in the image is the 110x12th element in the image matrix and THAT'S what I use as the element of the P1 column). Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: For you to train the classifier, you need a matrix X where each row will correspond to an image. If you want to use a coordinate representation, this means all images will have to be of the same size, say, M by N. So, the row of an image will have M times N elements, and the values will be the cluster assignments. The y will be as I described earlier.

Comment: ok got it now! Really appreciate your help!

Comment: I'll post the comment as the answer, would you mind to accept it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you to train the classifier, you need a matrix X where each row will correspond to an image. If you want to use a coordinate representation, this means all images will have to be of the same size, say, M by N. So, the row of an image will have M times N elements (features) and the corresponding feature values will be the cluster assignments. Class vector y will be whatever labels you have, that is one of the six different classes you mentioned through the comments above. You should keep in mind that if you use a coordinate representation, X can get very high-dimensional, and unless you have a large number of images, chances are your classifier will perform very poorly. If you have few images, consider using fractions of pixels belonging to clusters that I suggested in one of the comments: this can give you a shorter feature description that is invariant to rotation and translation, and may yield better classification.

Comment: Perfect. And you gave me another idea. In order to avoid the high-dimensionality problems this could cause in the case of coordinate representation, I ll try to use fourier shape descriptors on the clusters and pass THEM as input to the nn..I think this will do nicely.